# problems with serialization of sealed interface in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

Hoping you might be able to help, as I'm slowly tearing my hair out and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, but hope it might also be obvious.

```
@Serializable
data class Foo
(
   var text: String?
) : Bar



@Serializable
sealed interface Bar {

    var id: String?
    val hash: String
        get() {
            return this.toString().md5()
        }
    }

   fun save(): Boolean {
        return try {
            this.id = this.hash
            val tmp = Json.encodeToString(this)
            //save the number to Kali datastore.
            Datalayer.save(tmp)
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }



var aa = Foo("woo")
aa.save()
```

The issue I have, is when i get to aa.save(), I get

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'Foo' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'Bar'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
```

this is thrown from `val tmp = Json.encodeToString(this)`

but as far as I can tell, that's exactly what I have done? what have I done wrong? am I doing something overall stupid? I'm sort of stumped...

my kotlinx serialization is `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.0"),`

but also have set `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.7.20"`

I was sort of expecting it to work, but I got the error above. I've tried faffing with versions of things to see if that helps, but overall, no dice.

Comment: I think you  need to annotate your data class with a `@SerialName("Foo")` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like exception says the problem is that you haven't registered polymorphic serialization for your `Foo` class. You have several possible solutions to avoid it

1. If you don't want to use [Kotlin Serialization polymorphism](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md) then you can simply extract your `save` method into extension:

```kotlin
public inline fun <reified T: Bar> T.save(): boolean {
    return try {
        this.id = this.hash
        val tmp = Json.encodeToString(this)
        //save the number to Kali datastore.
        Datalayer.save(tmp)
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        false
    }
}
```

2. If you want to use [Kotlin Serialization polymorphism](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md) then you can register the serializer explicitly

```kotlin
val module = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(Bar::class) {
        subclass(Foo::class)
    }
}

val format = Json { serializersModule = module }
```

3. If you want to use [Kotlin Serialization polymorphism](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md) then you can use [sealed class](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes) instead of interface

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class Bar {

    abstract var id: String?

    val hash: String
        get() {
            return this.toString().md5()
        }
    }

   fun save(): Boolean {
        return try {
            this.id = this.hash
            val tmp = Json.encodeToString(this)
            //save the number to Kali datastore.
            Datalayer.save(tmp)
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }
}
```